# java binary search through list of names to print all the names between two names

Tags: java

I have a file that contains a list of names.  I have to do a search through the list and print out all the names that fall between the two names I search on.  Here's my code:

```
                           case '5'://broken

        System.out.println("Enter the first "last name" of the search.");
        String fLast= console.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the second "last name" of the search.");
        String lLast = console.next();
        String temp ="";
        if( fLast.compareTo(lLast)<0)
        {
            temp=lLast;
            lLast=fLast;
            fLast=temp;
        }
        nameToNameSearch(fLast,lLast);
        break;



 public void nameToNameSearch(String name1, String name2)
 {
ExtPerson[] nameToName = new ExtPerson[nMembes];
for(int x=1;x<nMembers-1; x++)
{
    if( bookMembers[x].lastName.compareTo(name1)==0|| bookMembers     
                        [x].lastName.compareTo    (name1)>0)
    {
        if(bookMembers[x].lastName.compareTo(name2)==0|| bookMembers
                            [x].lastName.compareTo(name1)<0)
        {
            int add=0;
            nameToName[add]=bookMembers[x];
            add++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would sort the names then use regex to extract the list from the toString() of the names... two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

If those are the terms of the assignment, you have to do one binary search to find the lower of the two names, then just print names from successively increasing indexes until you encounter the higher name. The higher name doesn't need to participate in the binary search at all really.